# Firebase CLI for one to one device notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, command-line-interface

I am trying to send a one to one device specific notification using FCM and Firebase CLI. For this I am sending the token from android to Firebase realtime database and trying to capture this token in CLI using an onwrite event. Here is the structure of the realtime database:

[image]

Here is the code where I am trying to capture the onwrite event and the token:

```js
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notification/{notification_id}').onWrite((data, context) => {
   const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
   const receiver_token = data.ref.parent.child(notification_id).child("token");
})
```

But I get the following error in the log:

> sendNotification
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite

I am writing CLI code for the first time and hence any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `onWrite` trigger gets a [`change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) parameter, which contains the snapshots before and after the change that triggered the code.

So you'll need to get the `change.before` or `change.after` to get the actual data.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notification/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
   const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
   const receiver_token = change.after.ref.parent.child(notification_id).child("token");
})
```

See the [Firebase documentation on `onWrite` triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value).

Note that it's much more common to use `onCreate` for this scenario, as you're typically deleting the notification after you've handled it.